# Unwanted free space on right side of webpage with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with unwanted free space on right side of my webpage.
I am using Bootstrap version 3.3.4. The problem disappeared when I used the following CSS for the body tag:

```
body{width: auto !important;overflow-x: hidden !important;}
```

But for mobile devices the problem still exists. I do not know what is causing it and I would like to get response from you.

Here is the complete example website: http://www.filedropper.com/zapytanienastackoverflow_1

Here is a screenshot with the white space. It appears when you scroll the webpage to the right.

[image: Screenshot of webpage showing white space]

Comment: I dont' see any white-space ! Can you please add some screenshot as well

Comment: Here is the photo with white space.
http://www.filedropper.com/pytanie

Comment: It appears when you scrool site to right

Comment: You should be able to look at the page in the object inspector and see what is in that white space and therefore what element is expanding/pushing the width of the `body`. TBH, without looking at the page ourselves the problem could literally be anything!?

Comment: You messed up with Bootstrap's default classes like container, row or col-xx-xx ! can you put your this site live somewhere and pass its link here ? it can't be fixed via screenshot, need working code

Comment: Here is the complete example website:
http://www.filedropper.com/zapytanienastackoverflow_1

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comment because of a reputation (I really understand these limitations, I didn't find single one which would actually help and not the other way around), so I have to post it as an answer.

The link you provided doesn't work so I can't be sure. But to me it looks like it could be a problem of the size of the picture in addition to the bootstrap gutter? What dimensions did you use with the picture?